# How to get Type of Nullable<Enum>?

Tags: c#

How can you do something like the following in C#?

```
Type _nullableEnumType = typeof(Enum?);
```

I guess a better question is why can't you do that when you can do this:

```
Type _nullableDecimalType = typeof(decimal?);
```

Comment: No such type really exists - how are you planning to use it? `Enum` itself is a reference type, not a value type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Enum` is **not an enum** - it is the base-class for enums, and is a reference-type (i.e. a `class`). This means that `Enum?` is illegal, as `Nullable<T>` has a restriction that `T : struct`, and `Enum` does  not satisfy that.

So: either use `typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(enumTypeKnownAtRuntime)`, or more simply, `typeof(EnumTypeKnownAtCompileTime?)`

You might also want to note that:

```
Enum x = {some value};
```

***is a boxing operation***, so you should usually avoid using `Enum` as a parameter etc.